# Close a SSH Session when it suspend

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, scripting

I start a ssh session on a remote host and execute a script on the remote host. The Script is an update script that change the remote IP.

Now my local bash script hanging on the line with this command:

ssh root@ip '/execute/this/script/test.sh/'...

Can I close this session after 3 seconds? The remote host reboots with this script and get a new IP.

Answer (score 0):

So all you've to do is press [Enter] key followed by ~..

```
  $ ~.
  $ Connection to xyz.com closed.
```

Ssh ESCAPE CHARACTERS List

```
 ~.      Disconnect.
 ~^Z     Background ssh.
 ~#      List forwarded connections.
 ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded connection / X11 sessions to terminate.
 ~?      Display a list of escape characters.
 ~B      Send a BREAK to the remote system (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).
 ~C      Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see above).  It also allows the cancellation of existing remote port-forwardings using -KR[bind_address:]port.
         !command allows the user to execute a local command if the PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in ssh_config(5).  Basic help is available, using the -h option.
 ~R      Request rekeying of the connection (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).
```

Comment: The Escape Characters doesn't work... the only way is ctrl + c or kill the pid with a additional tty